# an unconfigured ntp server appears in ntp client's list in solaris 9

Tags: solaris, ntp

So i have a solaris 9 server with running ntp client
I want it to poll 10.10.1.122 (local ntp server, there is no internet access)
so i configured the ntp server in the config file (below)
however when i do ntpq i get 2 servers, one of which i do not recognize
how do i disable this?

```
bash-3.2# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset    disp
==============================================================================
 10.10.1.122     LOCAL(0)         4 u    5   64    1    22.71  -368483 16000.0
 172.16.4.88     10.113.53.65     2 -   29   64    1     0.55  -63.870 16000.0



cat /etc/inet/ntp.conf 
# ident "@(#)ntp.client 1.3     00/07/17 SMI"
#
# /etc/inet/ntp.client
#
# An example file that could be copied over to /etc/inet/ntp.conf; it
# provides a configuration for a host that passively waits for a server
# to provide NTP packets on the ntp multicast net.
#

multicastclient 224.0.1.1

driftfile /var/ntp/ntp.drift
server 10.10.1.122
```

Answer (score 1):

The `multicastclient` line tells it to accept NTP packets from any host on your network that is multicasting to that address, as the comment above it says.